# Read multiple .csv files and extract (in new .csv files) all rows corresponding to non-empty cells across a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple .csv files (about 250). Each of them have exactly the same columns. All of them, have enough empty cells across many of the columns. I am interested to extract only all rows corresponding to non-empty cells of a specific column (named 20201-2.0). I believe it will work better with **pandas**.

So far, I have done the following step, which would work if continued:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = './'
column = ['20201-2.0']

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,?,?)
    li.append(df)
```

Is there a way I could extract only the rows corresponding to non-empty cells of column '20201-2.0' within df?

Or some other way?

George

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv').dropna(subset='20201-2.0')
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, I get the above error when I attempt your suggestion. Any ideas how I could successively add .csv file names without naming them? My .csv files that I need to input are called as "export_csv_0.csv", "export_csv_1.csv", etc.

Comment: just replace 'myfile.csv' with filename like you had originally

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried that, whenever I take out the ".dropna(subset='20201-2.0')" term is working, but when I add it I get the errors I mention above to RightmireM. I see that I am getting NaN in the empty places when I do the printing. Not sure what is wrong. I attach a small part of one of my csv files so you can understand.

Comment: https://uoe-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gpapanas_ed_ac_uk/Eby8Gq1FOXxCuvKeC8d1CHEBbRM7uzl2mss9EhauWSXJ6w?e=sc51Um

Comment: And a smaller version to open this online if you want: https://uoe-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gpapanas_ed_ac_uk/EfoxLcMZ9pZFjalzTS9wq6sBXtmkXWVd60_5S6Ojv5O5ug?e=dtbbaY

Comment: @G.Papas 20201-2.0 is not a column in your dataset. Changing the subset value to a real column such as '2020-2.0' and it works.  Please check your column names

Comment: Hi Chris, apologies, I am not sure what exactly you mean? Could you show in the code line you provided? Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

If the cells are truly "empty" versus holding a space string (" ") or a zero, then they will contain a "NaN" (a true null). You should be able to get them with...

```
df = li[li['20201-2.0'].notnull()]
```

A more complete example...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the dataframe "li" with a bunch of random numbers
li = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns= ['Col1', 'Col2','20201-2.0', 'Col4'])
# Make one sepcific cell below the "20201-2.0" column a null (NaN) value
li['20201-2.0'].iloc[2] = np.NaN
print(li) # See what youÄre working with

# Select for all rows, in all columns where the column "20201-2.0" is not a null
# This will return a full dataframe, with all the rows and columns - excluding any row(s) where the cell below "20201-2.0" was null
df = li[li['20201-2.0'].notnull()]
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you indeed. I think it will work. How could I incorporate the notnull() functionality within the df = pd.read_csv(filename,..) operation? I need this because I am treating csv files. Sorry, I am new to Python but getting there with these steps hopefully..

Comment: The `df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')` from @Chris is the right way to bring the CSVs into a dataframe. Personally, I would do the read and the separate as two different calls, simply for clarity. But his answer is a good way to get the data in one step. The way you're reading them all into `li` should be fine. And then remove the NaN rows with the `df = li[li['20201-2.0'].notnull()]` leaving you with a clean dataframe containing all the data from all the CSVs.

Comment: Thank you again. I attempted to do it your way and got an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Not sure why is that?

Comment: I also attempted Chris's suggestion:                                                                      for filename in all_files:
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1").dropna(subset='20201-2.0') but I get an error again: TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '20201-2.0' was passed. I think it does not like the way filename is inserted into the for loop.